# Pager not rendering in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: 2010, browser-compatibility

There isn't any custom CSS/JS attached to the site, but it has been reported to me, and I can verify, that for some reason the Pager control (td class = ms-paging) doesn't render in Internet Explorer 8. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but doesn't render in IE8.

At first I went digging through the CSS on Chrome to see if there was anything about it that may cause it to hide. Nothing there. Then I looked at the dev tools within IE8 and noticed that quite a few levels up, the table after #WebPartWPQ2 that included ms-paging div doesn't actually exist in IE8's view.

How can I get that part of the page to be sent to the user?

edit: good call Mike2500. We're using SharePoint 2010. Completely forgot to mention that, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say what environment you're using, but IE 8 is not supported in Office 365:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/supported-browsers-in-office-2013-and-office-365-proplus-HA102789344.aspx